# SMTP Mail does not sends for the second call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, smtp, sendmail

Here is the code which calls the `sendmail` method. The problem is that only the first call of `sendmail` sends the mail to the receiver. The second time when `sendmail` is called , it gets executed perfectly but never delivers any mail. If I put the application in debug mode and then execute it step by step both the mails get delivered. It seemed like the execution speed of the program is so fast that something goes wrong. Therefore I kept a delay below send function, so it started working fine for me, But I don't think it is a perfect solution. Anybody has any clue what is going on here.

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SendMailAdmin))
        {
        SendMail(SendMailFrom, SendMailAdmin, Subject, AdminMessageText + "<br>" + MessageText);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SendMailOwner))
        {
        SendMail(SendMailFrom, SendMailOwner, Subject, OwnerMessageText + "<br>" + MessageText);
        }

     public void SendMail(String MessageFrom, String MessageTo, String MessageSubject, String MessageBody)
            {
                MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
                Message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                Message.From = new MailAddress(MessageFrom);
                Message.To.Add(MessageTo);

                Message.Subject = MessageSubject;
                Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                Message.Body = MessageBody;

                try
                {
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SMTPServer, Convert.ToInt32(SMTPPort));

                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("{myusername}", "{mypassword}");

                    client.Send(Message);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Probably some flood protection somewhere low level. Call your method once and send array of `MessageTo` instead of one and it will work.

Comment: thanks shadow but the content is different for both the mail as you can see in the sendmail call , its different for AdminMessageText and OwnerMessageText . If i would have wanted to send 2 users then i could have used the CC but thats not the case. What do you mean by flood protection?

Comment: Hacked servers send thousands of spam emails.. one way to fight this is not allow sending emails one after the other quickly. So it's most likely such security measure in action. See the server event log to verify it. Anyway, sleeping for few seconds is not bad practice IMO can't think of better way, assuming the flood protection is low level and can't be disabled.

Comment: Might be an idea to have a using statement around `SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient` to ensure everything is disposed of in a timely fashion.

Comment: I think shadow you are right. This is not a .net issue , its the way mail server is configured.

Comment: Spender smtpclient object will be available only within the method block , so its gonna be disposed automatically

Comment: @parreenvatani - eventually, maybe - but it's always best to dispose of unmanaged objects when you know you don't need them any more. Especially in a loop.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee I tried but the smtpclient object doesnot contain dispose method

Comment: @PareenVatani It implements it explictly; so you can either cast it to IDisposable and call it directly or (better) use a `using` block.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee i tried doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think the only thing that'll work for you at this point is the delay code .@Shadow is right , this is how servers are configured